# running winapps on elementaryOS

Tags: applications

I am wondering if winapps is also running on eOS

Please find the link below:

https://github.com/Fmstrat/winapps

I am waiting for eOS6 and running still popOS for now.

Answer (score 1):

winapps is a script which uses kvm to run windows in a vm. You can use kvm on eOS, so winapps should also be working.